# FancyBox: показывать галерею картинок

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript, изображения

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

http://fancybox.net/howto

Есть галерея картинок. Делая по примерам, задавая стиль "fancybox-thumb" после открытия снизу от изображения появляются все картинки в уменьшенном размере.

Но в моем случае, надо передавать массив ссылок на изображения. Делаю это так:

```
$.fancybox.open(
    [
        {href: "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_m.jpg"},
        {href: "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7152/6394238505_c94fdd1d89_m.jpg"}
    ],
    {}
)
```

Но при этом не могу добавить снизу все мини-изображения. Как это сделать?

Немного тут: http://jsfiddle.net/IVsevolod/w3by2/ (но там стили похоже не все прогрузились)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос старый, но тем не менее:

```
$("#xx").click(function(){
    $.fancybox.open([
        {href: "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_m.jpg"},
        {href: "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7152/6394238505_c94fdd1d89_m.jpg"}
    ],
    {
        helpers: {
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });
});
```

В опциях вы сразу задавали `thumbs`, в то время как настройки для миниатюр надо указывать в `helper`-e.

**Пример: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3by2/1/)**

Comment: Спасибо :)
всегда пригодиться, знать надо )

Comment: не за что :)